# Angular Flex layout with Collapsible cards. Row problem

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I'm building a feature with Angular 8 where a list of "templates" (my object) is displayed in expansive cards.
I want to show 3 expansive cards per row.

-Cards are shown collapsed by default
-Everything is displayed correctly, both the rows and the colums. However,

When I expand a card, the card expands correctly, but all the row that's under it get's pushed.

I've tried setting fx layout to row, fxlayout xs to column and flex-wrap wrap

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" class="grid-wrap">
      <app-collapsible-card fxFlex.gt-xs="50%" [fxFlex.gt-md]="100/3" *ngFor="let template of certificatedTemplates">
      </app-collapsible-card>
</div
```

css:

```
.grid-wrap{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The expected result would be that only the card under the card that I'm expanding gets pushed, instead of the whole row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzNZm.jpg

As seen in the image, when I open card 3, card 4 and cad 5 get pushed to the bottom too. This should not happen. I understand that it's due to the fact that they are in another row, but I'm not sure how to workaround this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u9nhgs8m/ I made this quick jsfiddle to demonstrate how to do this. The fiddle uses bootstrap, but that should be easily convertible to angular flex. Basically use one row and separate your cards in three columns within that row.

Comment: @Noremac sadly we're using material, but I will try to adapt it. The fiddle shows what I want to do, let's see how it goes, thank you so much.